# Connect to dockerized rest service from mobile app in development

Tags: android, networking, docker, openshift

We are developing both a mobile app and a backend REST service. The rest service (and database) run in OpenShift (using Minishift), as docker containers.

We would like to be able to develop both the mobile app and the backend rest service on the same laptop. But, when running the app, we are not able to connect to the REST services running in OpenShift.

How can we enable requests from the app to be networked to the applications running inside OpenShift, in a local development environment?

We can, from the mobile device, browse to the rest service, when the service is NOT dockerized - that is, when running on the host, but when running in OpenShift (dockerized).

Comment: How is OpenShift running locally? oc cluster up? vagrant vm?

Comment: Take a step by step approach. Is your service running for sure? can you try running on host directly in place of container? Or curl/wget your service from inside and then outside of the service container. Do a ping test from mobile app location to REST service location etc...

Comment: I have updated the question to show (1) how we run OpenShift (as minishift) and (2) that we have been going step by step.

Comment: @Magick ok, have you created a route to expose the service?

Comment: Yes, the service is working fine. The issue is about how to network requests from a mobile app to a laptop, to openshift.

Comment: The problem is that MiniShift is possibly using an IP local to your computer and isn't actually visible outside of your computer. So even if you are using the ``nip.io`` address used by MiniShift for your application, if coming from a mobile app on device on same local area network, it may not know to route requests to the local computer running MiniShift. Are you using the ``nip.io`` address on your mobile device for the application, or are using an IP address hoping it will work?